# Pass a Byte[] in HttpRequest headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, encoding, type-conversion, aes

I've been struggling with a small problem. I am trying to create a session ( which is an random string that is encrypted using an AES key ). This naturally is returned as a byte[].

So my code looks like this.

```
 public class CryptoService : ICryptoService
    {
        const int PASSWORD_LENGTH = 32;
        private static Encoding encoder = Encoding.UTF8;

        public byte[] EncrpyRandomPassword(string nonceValue)
        {
            var randomString = RandomPasswordGenerator.RandomString(PASSWORD_LENGTH);

            var keyByte = encoder.GetBytes(nonceValue);
            using Aes myAes = Aes.Create();

            byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(randomString, keyByte, myAes.IV);

            return encrypted;
        }
}
```

This array then it's passed to the controller in the following class.

```
 public interface ISession
    {
        byte[] SessionKey { get; }
        string SessionKeyASCI { get; }
        string SessionKeyUTF8 { get; }
        bool IsValid { get; }
        void ValidateSession();
    }

  public class Session : ISession
    {
        private byte[] m_SessionKey;
        private bool m_IsValid;

        public byte[] SessionKey => m_SessionKey;

        public bool IsValid => m_IsValid;

        public string SessionKeyASCI => Encoding.ASCII.GetString(m_SessionKey);

        public string SessionKeyUTF8 => Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m_SessionKey);
}
```

like this.

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSessionAsync(string nonceValue)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nonceValue))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"'{nameof(nonceValue)}' cannot be null or empty.", nameof(nonceValue));
        }
    var session = await _sessionProvider.CreateSession(nonceValue);

    return Ok(session);
}
```

This in postman results in

```
{
    "sessionKey": "lI+ZRpzqP6E2vErt+wK4dw+nFM0mm0q1Pc2PoAuCssybVI07jUIQ5VWGR2yXCmX5",
    "isValid": false,
    "sessionKeyASCI":"???F????6?J???w??&?J?=???\u000b????T?;?B?U?Gl?\ne?",
    "sessionKeyUTF8":"���F��?�6�J���w��&�J�=͏�\u000b��̛T�;�B�U�Gl�\ne�"
}
```

Now my question are.

1. What encoding did c# use to return "sessionKey" as the string I see. (I thought it uses ASCI/UTF8, but from what I've been looking here, they are different.
2. If I use the "sessionKey" as a byte[] in a post action, it works ok and I am able to convert back to string the value, but I would like to pass this SessionKey as a Header in the request, where the value is a string which leads to my 3rd question.
3. How would be the best way to encode a AES Key result in a string that could be used in a Header ( then of course convert it back to byte[]).

EDIT

Encrypt method

```
  static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
        byte[] encrypted;

        // Create an Aes object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return encrypted;
    }
```

Comment: Neither ASCII nor UTF8 are designed to take an *arbitrary* sequence of bytes and turn them into a sensible sequence of characters. There are byte sequences those encodings can never produce and so they cannot "decode" such sequences sensibly. You should be looking at something like Base64. See all of those question marks in diamonds in your example? That's where no such decoding makes sense.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever then how does Web.API/Postman do it naturally. ```sessionKey``` is the same sequance of bytes as ```sessionKeyASCI```. If I pass that sequance as a byte[] in a post action it also converts back to the same byte[] in my API. So what the framework does default works, but I i have a problem using it in the Headers.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever indeed the array using Convert.ToBase64string(sessionkey) will return the same thing that Window does. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @CiucaS HTTP POST data is part of the body of HTTP. The headers in the HTTP protocol are text (and GET only uses those) but the body is binary all the way. It usually contains text, but any byte value will be received *fine*, even if they don't make sense in ASCII or UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your questions

1. Web servers tend to pass back the encoding they use in the `Content-Type` header, look in the "Headers" tab in postman to discover what encoding your response was sent in.
2. Isn't a question
3. "Best" way is subjective. HTTP headeras must be strings, and therefore it entirely up to you how you encode a byte array as a string in order to send in a header - as long as your server-side code understands how to decode it you're all good.

Comment: from Postman it looks like "application/json; charset=utf-8" but then why is my sessionKey different from sessionKeyUTF8

Comment: @CiucaS Because you're assuming that the bytes were originally encoded using UTF8 encoding. What is `EncryptStringToBytes_Aes` doing?

Comment: also using both of the UTF8 or ASCI as Headers throws error in postman "Invalid character in header content ["SessionKey"]" as they are invalid chars. That's what I was referring at the best. Because it feels like I am missing something, but not sure what.

Comment: I've added the ```EncryptStringToBytes_Aes``` method to the post.